# Testing API error with supertest and jest fails even though response is correct

Tags: node.js, http, testing, jestjs, supertest

I'm using `jest 23.1.0` and `supertest 3.1.0`. I'm writing some tests for my backend and things have been going ok, however for a specific case of a specific route, the test is failing even though the response object seems to contain the right information. The test is to check if a parameter is valid JSON, and is as such:

```
describe('GET /graph', () => {
    it('invalid JSON', (done) => {
        request(app)
            .get('/graph')
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
            .expect(415)
            .then(done);
        });
});
```

In this case I'm not actually sending any parameter at all, but even if I do send some invalid JSON the issue is the same. Both cases trigger the same backend check anyway, which is:

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {

    let dataParameters;
    try {
        dataParameters = JSON.parse(req.query.dataParameters);
    }
    catch(error) {
        return(res.status(415).send({
            message: "Request parameters are not a valid JSON object",
            other: `${error.name} - ${error.message}`
        }));
    }
    ...
```

When I run jest, the test fails and the output to the console is this:

```
  GET /graph
    ✕ invalid JSON (6ms)

  ● GET /graph › invalid JSON

    Failed: Object {
      "header": Object {
        "connection": "close",
        "content-length": "125",
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "date": "Tue, 26 Jun 2018 13:58:48 GMT",
        "etag": "W/\"7d-GGhtZ8CfzWfmANZW28JTNC5bNjU\"",
        "x-powered-by": "Express",
      },
      "req": Object {
        "data": undefined,
        "headers": [Object],
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:35875/graph",
      },
      "status": 415,
      "text": "{\"message\":\"Request parameters are not a valid JSON object\",\"other\":\"SyntaxError - Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0\"}",
    }

      at Env.fail (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:537:34)
```

So looking at the object jest prints it seems the route is returning the right HTTP status and message, however instead of supertest handling that, the actual test itself is failing. I use the same response format and testing technique for testing other API errors and this doesn't happen. I've tried changing the `request` parameters, error codes and various other things but to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had issues with passing parameters into Done() causing a similar issue.

Try changing your

`.then(done)`

to

`.then(() => { done() })`

and see if that fixes it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: What a fantastic idea Dan.